# Is there a way to have a public ip address when disconnected from all routers?

Tags: windows, networking, android

I am programming a mobile device that needs to access HTTP services. There are web services running on a Windows box that I would like to access from the Android device. So I am doing development across Android and Windows. The Android device is connected to the Windows machine via a USB cable.

When I am working offline such as camping, or at a demo, I don’t have a LAN connection. The web services don't have an adapter to attach to so there is no IP address that the Android device can connect to. Even if I set a fixed IP address onto an adapter and that adapter reports as disconnected then that IP address is not available.

The loopback adapter will give me `127.0.0.1` on the Windows machine but that is not publicly accessible from the Android device (or is it?)

How can I provide web services on the Windows machine that are accessible from Android without being connected to a network?

I could accept buying a WiFi travel router as being the answer though I am surprised that that is the only way to do it as it must be a common problem for people doing presentations with multiple devices.

Comment: What sort of cable are you using to connect the two devices? You could perhaps use an OTG network adapter and then plug a network  crossover cable into the Windows machine and the other into the OTG network adapter. Then assign a static address to the NIC on the Windows machine and one on the Android device (e.g 192.168.0.1 on windows, 192.168.0.2 on the android device.) As long as they are on the same subnet you should be able to then connect. You'd just need to undo the settings once you are reconnecting online.

Comment: @Enigman I am using a USB cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is to make an ad hoc wireless network on the laptop, but android often won't connect to ad hoc networks. You could try with your device though.

So I'd recommend instead buying a [USB powered travel router](http://nerdtechy.com/best-portable-mini-travel-wifi-router-2016). You can power it from your laptop when camping on battery power, and will hopefully give you a lot of flexibility in how you network your devices.